# CommonsXsdSchemaCollection and import statements

Tags: spring-ws

I'm using [CommonsXsdSchemaCollection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/xml/xsd/commons/CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.html) to configure validation and WSDL generation but the default URI resolver doesn't support my use case. I need to load an XSD with import statements where the schema location is a symbolic URL and the linked schemas are actually on the classpath. A URI resolver which can understand catalog files would be ideal, but couldn't find any, so I resorted to writing a modified version of `CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.ClasspathUriResolver` (`CommonsXsdSchemaCollection`'s inner class which defines its default resolver) with the capability to rewrite URLs.

Are there more straightforward ways to do the job?

Thanks,
  Gianluca